# Include header in the 'grep' result

Tags: shell, grep

Is there a way to combine 'head -1' and 'grep' command into one for all the files in a directory and redirect the output to an output file. I can do this using 'sed' but it seems that it is not as fast as grep.

```
sed -n '1p;/6330162/p' infile*.txt > outfile.txt
```

Using grep I can do the following one file at a time:

```
head -1 infile1.txt;  grep -i '6330162' infile1.txt > outfile.txt
```

However, I need to do it for all files in the directory. Inserting a wildcard is not helping as it is printing headers first and then the grep output.

Comment: Of course it's not as fast as grep; grep is doing less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for file in *
do
  [ "$file" = outfile.txt ] && continue
  head -n 1 "$file"
  grep -i '...' "$file"
done > outfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @Ignacio. I am also adding file name to keep track of where the data is coming from in the output file and thus added 'file "$file";'. However, in the output it is attaching 'ASCII text' for ex: file1.txt: ASCII text

Comment: this is such a common use case, I am baffled why there is no straightforward and simple solution for it

Answer (score 49):

The following means you only need type the command once (rather than using && and typing it twice), it's also quite simple to understand.

```
some-command | { head -1; grep some-stuff; }
```

e.g.

```
ps -ef | { head -1; grep python; }
```

UPDATE: This only seems to work for `ps`, sorry, but I guess this is usually what people want this for.

If you want this to work for an arbitrary command, it seems you must write a mini script, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

first_line=true

while read -r line; do
    if "${first_line}"; then
        echo "$line"
        first_line=false
    fi
    echo "$line" | grep $*
done
```

Which I've named `hgrep.sh`.  Then you can use like this:

```
ps -ef | ./hgrep.sh -i chrome
```

The nice thing about this approach is that we are using `grep` so *some* of the flags work exactly the same.

**NOTE** This doesn't work for flags that don't operate line-by-line, e.g. `-A`, `-B`, `-C`, etc.  I see no trivial way to adjust the script to do this, as it likely requires buffering, which could break the latency expectations when comparing to pure `grep`.  **Open to ideas!**

Comment: NB: This seems to work with `ps`, but not any other command (df, ls, cat, etc).

Comment: @BrianPapantonio Yes, no idea why that is, rather strange.  Do you know why?

Comment: Upon further investigation, I see that it works with `ps -e` but not `ps`. Apparently `ps -e` is sending the header line first, then not sending anything, then buffering the rest of the output. `head` must think the stream is closed after the first line, so it exits, leaving grep to see the rest.
tl;dr: This trick works by accident.

Comment: @BrianPapantonio Updated answer with a warning.

Comment: This is **not** a generic solution! I believe it only works iff the first command buffers its entire output (application specific and limited by buffer size) before sending it off, because `head -1` will send SIGPIPE once it's done reading, causing the first command to stop.

Comment: @BrianPapantonio Can you please upvote whichever answer you think is best? Or provide an alternative?

Comment: @samthebest I did post an alternative.

Comment: @I0b0  Thanks, it's pretty nice for a one liner.  I've ended up just writing a script as I cannot see a neat one liner that preserves the `grep` flags.

Comment: The loop doesn't work with the B/C/A flags to grep as it sends the output line-per line to grep.

Comment: It does not work with the m flag either. This is a bad solution.

Comment: Given that the value of `$first_line` is either `true` or `false`, you can write `if "$first_line"; then ...` rather than `if [ "${first_line}" = "true" ]; then ...`.

Comment: @SiXoS, thanks, any ideas to improve it? I've updated the answer with the caveats you spotted.

Answer (score 22):

This will work by using a single receiving command:

```
some-command | sed -n '1p;/PATTERN/p'
```

It's also easy to use this with multi-line headers:

```
$ sudo netstat --tcp --udp --listening --numeric --program | sed --quiet '1,2p;/ssh/p'
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1258/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1258/sshd
```

To [reiterate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920317/include-header-in-the-grep-result/50204811#comment87426554_19356846), @samthebest's solution will only work in very specific situations; this will work with any command that writes to standard output.

Comment: I get `sed: illegal option -- -`.  Will `PATTERN` work the same as `grep` or `egrep`?

Comment: There are different versions of `sed`; I've changed it to use a more portable (but less readable) flag.

Comment: This works and is useful, but the question asks for "... in grep result".  I guess the point being one may be more familiar with `grep` than `sed`.  For example how do you do `-i` with `sed`?

Comment: You add an `i` before the last `p`. As far as I know this site has never shied away from proposing alternative tools, since limiting the answerer's options makes the answers lower quality and less likely to be applicable to others.

Comment: Yes, as I said "this works and is useful" hence upvoting.  Nevertheless I would still like to see a one liner that uses `grep`.

Answer (score 2):

I would have done that :

```
ps -fe | awk '{ if ( tolower($0) ~ /network/ || NR == 1 ) print $0}'
```

Comment: This awk is overly complex; awk takes predicate(s) before the open bracket to filter lines. Furthermore, `print $0` is redundant when it's by itself. This can be simplified to `ps -fe | awk 'NR == 1; /network/'`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script `hgrep` to replace the command `grep`:

```
#!/bin/bash

content=`cat`
echo "$content" | head -1
echo "$content" | tail -n+2 | grep "$@"
```

Then `df -h | hgrep tmpfs` will output header and lines include `tmpfs`

The quote is vital.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Curious you can use xargs with your cmd.

```
find /mahesh  -type f |xargs -I {} -t /bin/sh -c "head -1 {}>>/tmp/out.x|grep -i 6330162 {} >>/tmp/out.x"
```

Where /mahesh is dir in which your files are and output is placed inside /tmp/out.x

Answer (score 0):

If perl is ok, you can use: `some-command | perl -ne 'print if $.==1 | /some-stuff/'`

Answer (score 0):

No header:     `netstat -lt | grep "smtp"`

With header:
`{ netstat -lt | head -1;  netstat -lt | grep "smtp"; }`

```
[root@k8s-5 ]#  netstat -lt | grep "smtp"
tcp        0      0 localhost:smtp          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
[root@k8s-5 ]#

[root@k8s-5 ]# { netstat -lt | head -1;  netstat -lt | grep "smtp"; }
Active Internet connections (only servers)
tcp        0      0 localhost:smtp          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
[root@k8s-5 ]#
```

Note: `{ command1; command2; }` -->  combines output of both commands.