# Why does a pipe to a command group only work for some commands?

Tags: shell, pipe, pipeline

I was interested in keeping the header of the input in the `grep` output just like in the question [Include header in the 'grep' result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920317/include-header-in-the-grep-result).

Although a working solution (using `sed`) is presented right in the question, the [answer with most upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19356846/711006) attracted my attention. It allows utilizing `grep --color`, for example. It suggests piping the input to a [command group](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) with the commands `head` and `grep`, e.g.:

```
ps -ef | { head -1; grep python; }
```

However, as written in the linked answer and a comment, this does not work with all commands on the left side of the pipe. It works well with `ps` or `lsof` but does not work for `df`, `ls` and others. When using them, only the output of the first command in the group is printed:

```
$ df | { head -1; grep '/'; }
Filesystem                                   1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
$
```

Could anyone explain why piping to a command group only works for some commands? Is there any way to make it work universally?

Comment: In general I think you shouldn't rely on the second command receiving any input.

Comment: You can use `awk` to print first line or matching lines... `ps -ef | awk 'NR==1 || /python/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is in [comments of the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920317/include-header-in-the-grep-result/19356846#comment60534720_19356846).

> Apparently `ps -e` is sending the header line first, then not sending anything, then buffering the rest of the output. `head` must think the stream is closed after the first line, so it exits, leaving `grep` to see the rest.

It only works by accident.

> Is there any way to make it work universally?

Everything is possible, but, you may need to recode and recompile everything else. So... not possible, sorry.